# Como criar uma lista de Roles no Claim usando ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Fiz uma autenticação usando `Claims` com `cookies` no `ASP.NET Core`.

No Método abaixo, o objeto por parâmetro traz as informações de login e dentro dele tem uma lista chamada `PerfisDeAcesso`. Como faço para atribuir essa lista ao `ClaimTypes.Role`? Pergunto isso porque ele só aceita um único elemento do tipo `string` e minha lista tem mais de um elemento (do tipo `string`).

Não foi aceito um `foreach` dentro.

```
 private async Task<IActionResult> SignInAsync(Usuario usuario)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, usuario.CodUsuario),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuario.Login),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, /* lista com os perfis de acesso */)

        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar individualmente, como uso o Authorize do próprio asp.net core faço assim, ele fica responsável em serializar isso internamente:

```
claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));
```